# How to use a 2d array to declare an array_view or array object in c++ AMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpgpu, c++-amp

I'm trying to use an array such as `int myarray[2][3]` to initialize an `array_view` object. I've tried `array_view<int, 2> a(2,3, myarray);` However that does not work. I would also like to be able to do the same thing with a vector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `array_view<int, 2> a(2, 3, *myarray);`

**EDIT :**

A vector of (fixed-size) vectors can't be used directly to init an array_view object.

However you could do something like that:

```
vector< vector<int> > my_multi_vector; // Fill my_multi_vector with data
vector<int> my_composed_vector;
for(int i = 0, ie = my_multi_vector.size(); i != ie; ++i)
    my_composed_vector.insert(my_composed_vector.end(), my_multi_vector[i].begin(), my_multi_vector[i].end());
array_view<int, 2> a(2, 3, &my_composed_vector.front());
```

Comment: Do you want to construct a vector with an int array or an array_view with a vector?

Comment: array_view with a vector of vectors

Comment: Oh! I thought one can create an array_view only around array as opposed to vectors!

Answer (score 3):

Baltram’s method is correct.
And you can replace

```
array_view<int, 2> a(2, 3, &my_composed_vector.front());
```

by

```
array_view<int, 2> a(2, 3, my_composed_vector);
```

to make it simpler.

Here is an even more simpler way:

```
int myarray[2][3];
int *p = &myarray[0][0];
array_view<int, 2> a(2, 3, p);
```

Thanks,